# Using jQuery to append a link to another page

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm trying to do something very simple but my searches have come up empty. I am trying to append a button that will simply link you to another page.

Like this:

```
$("#something").append("<br><center><input type='button' value='Go' onclick='Link to another page'></center>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you wanna keep the same markup, use this:

```
$("#something").append("<br><center><input type='button' value='Go' onclick='location.href=\"url\"'></center>");
```

Replace the `url` with something like `index.html` or something.

#### Suggestions:

1. I recommend having an `<a>` tag for this kind of stuffs.
2. Replace `<center>...</center>` tags with `<div style="text-align: center;"></div>`.
3. Use unobtrusive way of JavaScript by giving this way:

   ```
   $("#something").append("<div style='text-align: center;'><input type='button' value='Go' id="button"></div>");
   $("#button").click(function(){ location.href = 'url'; });
   ```